# Memory issues exporting large datasets with node

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I'm running into memory limitations when exporting a certain number of rows.  I got a node heap out of memory error.  Currently I can export about 2 million rows, which equates to a 150 MB csv file.  I have seen examples of people exporting gb of data with node however.

This is the relevant part of the function where the memory usage increases to the point node crashes:

```
const { Pool } = require("pg");

...

      pool.query(queryData, (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
          app.logger(`Unable to query ${externalDataSource.name} PS database with query "${queryData.text}"`,
            "error", modelLogType, modelUserName, modelFileName, __line);
          reject(`Unable to query ${externalDataSource.name} database with specified query`);
        } else if (res && res.rows) {

          resolve(res.rows);
        }
        pool.end();
      });
```

I've seen a few libraries like pg-streams and some others, but I'm not sure what the best "modern" approach to this problem is.  Would it be better to have the database generate the csv and pass it through, or is it better to handle it with node and "chunks"?

Comment: What "memory limitation" are you running into?  Is there an error message?

Comment: You want to use the pg.Cursor API:  https://node-postgres.com/api/cursor

Comment: You definitely need to use a stream. Streams rows from pg out to a file.

Comment: do you have an example of using a stream?  I see a lot of implementations but not sure what the best option is for large datasets.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase nodes memory limit as follows:

```
node --max-old-space-size=1024 your_script.js #increase to 1gb
node --max-old-space-size=2048 your_script.js #increase to 2gb
node --max-old-space-size=3072 your_script.js #increase to 3gb
node --max-old-space-size=4096 your_script.js #increase to 4gb
node --max-old-space-size=5120 your_script.js #increase to 5gb
node --max-old-space-size=6144 your_script.js #increase to 6gb
node --max-old-space-size=7168 your_script.js #increase to 7gb
node --max-old-space-size=8192 your_script.js #increase to 8gb
```

Comment: I tried this and it still failed.  I raised it up to 7168.  The file would have been about 2-300 megabytes.

Comment: You need to post the error you're getting.  Hard to help otherwise.

Comment: Node.js heap out of memory gets thrown inconsistently or the process terminates.